# Formula to build and fill a color in a cell in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have Red, Green,Blue ,alpha values as columns in an excel sheet.
I want to should the color corresponding to these value in the next column.
Ex R = 255, G = 0, B = 0 Alpha = 255  ==> Fill cell with RED color.

Comment: [http://tinyurl.com/p7kmqe8](http://tinyurl.com/p7kmqe8)

Answer (score 0):

With an in-built formula it can't be done without using something like VBA as well.